# Difference between Layer und Pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, layer

I have a understanding problem. I use a MVC pattern and now i should describe my used layers..but i don't really know the difference between pattern and layer.

are these are my layers (i mean they are also my patterns only named model,view, controller):
UI
Controller
Model
Persistence

Comment: I think by layer what is meant is abstraction layer, i.e. going from the general to the concrete and how you achieve that architecturally. But just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

A [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) is a name for a reusable software solution.

[Layering](http://www.vico.org/pages/PatronsDisseny/Pattern%20Layers/) is [one such pattern](http://www.stevenblack.com/PTN-Layers.html).

Comment: is therefore mvc based on 3-tier or do i have 4 layers (UI, controller, model, persistence) ?

Comment: @peter - MVC does not include persistence as a pattern. I would say each component is a layer/tier and additionally there is the persistence layer/tier.